# Concatenate columns that have leading zeros and decimals

Tags: excel, concatenation, leading-zero

I am trying to merge multiple columns together, but run into an issue with leading zeros.

```
Column F            Column G        Column H        Column I
0000000033.33           +              01              09


=CONCATENATE(F1&G1&H1&I1)
```

Results:
33.33+19

There are more columns containing leading zeros at different lengths and some columns that have symbols. I just want it to pick up exactly what is in each column.

I have tried numerous formulas searching Google. I have applied text format to the column too which does not help (I also tried applying text format to the column with the leading zeros and it just deletes all the zeros).

I have tried the following query in Access as well, and it removes the leading zeros as well:

```
Select *, [Field5] & [Field6] & [Field7] As FullNumber
From Table 1
```

Comment: I tried to duplicate your issue, but it seemed to work for me, putting together the contents of the cells as is with leading zero's.  I formatted my columns `F` through `I` as text before I entered the values, but then I formatted them as general and then back to text without changing the results.   Not sure if you may have some default setting or version issue.  I'm running Excel 2016 in Windows 10.

Comment: ^yes, I believe you are right about my setting/version Issue. I am running on windows 7/ Excel 2010. I'm saying you're right because none of the solutions online apply and it seems like they are the correct solutions. How do I identify what setting I need to change?

Comment: @ReyJuna Forgot to tag you. Also, when I format a column to text it will not accept formulas (formula is written as text).

Comment: I have no knowledge of any way to do this in settings.  I just ran through all my Excel settings and didn't see anything promising.  Since you mention having a similar issue in Access it may not even be an Excel setting, if that is truly the cause.

Comment: I would be interested to know if anyone else in the community can duplicate your issue.

Comment: re: your comment "when I format a column to text..."  Do columns `F` through `I` have these values or are they the result of a formula?  (Although that would seem to make it easier to keep the leading zeros.)  If you have your concatenate in the same column as your data, I would suggest moving it, or just go back to that cell and format as general.

Comment: I'm no Access guru, but are you sure that `As FullNumber` is correct since you are really wanting text?

Comment: I believe the only way this behaviour can exist is if a custom number format has been applied to the cells ("0000000000.00" for column F and "00" for column H and I). If you can confirm this by inspecting the number format in the Home menu, then it'll get you closer to an answer. You can either replicate the custom number format with the TEXT function, or use a VBA function to automatically do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems formatting has been applied (and you are not showing us what is in the cells, only what *appears* to be in the cells) so with only a single example to work with (coupled with uncertainty about what it is you want) I suggest saving as .csv and importing via Get External Data (with Text chosen for Column data format) *then* concatenating.